# Logstash parses logfiles to wrong index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have an elasticsearch instance, which parses my logfiles according to my regex pattern, which takes the date from the logfile. Then the date should be used as the index pattern for elasticsearch purposes. This is where it gets wrong. My logstash-pipeline-config-file looks as follows:

```
input {

beats {
        port => "5044"
    }

}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{LOGGERLEVEL:log}%{PIPE:k}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:datetime}%{GREEDYDATA:data}"}
    }
    date {
        match => ["datetime", "ISO8601"]
        timezone => "Europe/Helsinki"


    }

}
output {

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }


}
```

LOGGERLEVEL and PIPE are user defined regexes. This version parses the logs as it should but it indexes the first two hours of the day to the date before. If I change the config-file as follows, elasticsearch will ignore the first two hours altogether:

```
input {

beats {
        port => "5044"
    }

}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{LOGGERLEVEL:log}%{PIPE:k}%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:datetime}%{GREEDYDATA:data}"}
    }
    date {
        match => ["datetime", "ISO8601"]
        timezone => "Europe/London"


    }

}
output {

    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }


}
```

How should I configurate my pipeline that one day would be indexed as a whole and under the same index that is the date found from the logfile?

Comment: Are you sure the first two hours are ignored in your second try? I wouldn't have expected that, perhaps something else went wrong.

Comment: Ah! You're right. When I use the second option, the indexing is correct but timestamps are behind by two hours. I don't know why the indexing is from 2am to 2am and not from midnight to midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Using kibana, go to management -> advanced settings and change the dateFormat:tz to the desired format. In my case I have to use the second configuration and select Europe/London from kibana-settings.